# Reading data from a structure give error:

Tags: c++

Bear with me and my question as I am not a very experienced programmer.

In my program I have a structure defines as here:

```
    // Screen Cell Structure
//
// The Symbol is the ASCII code of the character to be drawn plus the following special symbols:
// \xA1: left arrow
// \xA2: right arrow


struct CDU_Cell
{
unsigned char   Symbol;
unsigned char   Color;  // any of CDU_COLOR_ defines
unsigned char   Flags;  // a combination of CDU_FLAG_ bits
};

// CDU Screen Data Structure

#define CDU_COLUMNS 24
#define CDU_ROWS    14

struct CDU_Screen
{
CDU_Cell Cells[CDU_COLUMNS][CDU_ROWS];
bool Powered;   // true if the CDU is powered
};

// CDU Screen Cell Colors
#define CDU_COLOR_WHITE 0   
#define CDU_COLOR_CYAN  1
#define CDU_COLOR_GREEN 2
#define CDU_COLOR_MAGENTA   3
#define CDU_COLOR_AMBER 4
#define CDU_COLOR_RED   5

// CDU Screen Cell flags
#define CDU_FLAG_SMALL_FONT 0x01    // small font, including that used for line headers 
#define CDU_FLAG_REVERSE    0x02    // character background is highlighted in reverse video
#define CDU_FLAG_UNUSED 0x04    // dimmed character color indicating inop/unused entries
```

Then I have this function where I want to store the data

```
void ProcessCDUData(PMDG_NGX_CDU_Screen *pS)
{

for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < 24; j++) {

     str33      = pS->Cells[j][i];
```

so I can write it out to a window with this

```
// Create a text layout for a string
IDWriteTextLayout *pTextLayout1;


const WCHAR str1[] = str33
pDWriteFactory->CreateTextLayout(
    str1,
    24,
    //sizeof(24)/sizeof(str1[0]),
    pTextFormat,
    0.0f,
    0.0f,
    &pTextLayout1
);
```

My problem is that I can't store the data to str33.

I get a error:

```
no suitable conversion function from "PMDG_NGX_CDU_Cell" to "char" exists
```

What should the correct code be here? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where did you define `str33`? It doesn't seem to appear in the above.

Comment: I defined it like this:    char str33;

Comment: Oh, that's a problem, then. Read up on [`string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/).

Comment: You have some misunderstanding about types, pointers, solid objects, char array, char pointer, char vs.

Comment: Yes, that is my problem

Comment: `const WCHAR str1[] = str33` What is this line?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently str33 is type of CDU_Cells :

```
str33      = pS->Cells[j][i];
```

And you try to affect in str1 who is of WCHAR type (char apparently). Maybe can you do an explicit conversion from CDU_Cells to WCHAR ?

Comment: It is here I come to short. If I put the code to a console program and have  a line  printf("%d ", (((pS)->Cells)[j])[i]); it prints to the screen

Answer (score 0):

The type conversion should be meaningful if you want to access the data after the type conversion. If you just want to store the data in a different data type, then typecast using pointer data type and use memcpy to copy.

Example:

```
struct A
{
   char str1[20];
   char str2[20];
};

char str3[40];
strcut A mystruct;

memcpy(str3, (char *) (&mystruct), sizeof(struct mystruct));
```